# Cannot add a child node that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without measure function

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[Click here for an image of the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ynID.png)

Trying to create a log-in form which reads information from a firebase database through axios; getting an error related to YogaNodes. Read about this; I think there must be something wrong with the JSX syntax. But both SublimeLinter (the text editor I use) and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Pretty sure the components imported (Card, CardSection, Button, Spinner) are fine since those are reusable components I have been using with my other Apps.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button, Spinner, CardSection, AlbumDetail } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
    state = { loggedIn: null, albums: [] };

 componentWillMount() {
 firebase.initializeApp({
 apiKey: 'xx',
 authDomain: 'xx',
 databaseURL: 'xx',
 projectId: 'xx',
 storageBucket: 'xx',
 messagingSenderId: 'xx'
});

    axios.get('https://xx')
            .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    });
  }

  renderAlbums() {
        return this.state.albums.map(album => 
            <AlbumDetail key={album.District} album={album} />);
    }

  renderContent() {
    switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
      case true:
        return (
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
            Log Out
          </Button>
        </CardSection>  
        );
      case false:
        return <LoginForm />;
      default:
        return <Spinner size='large' />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText='Authentication' />
        console.log(this.state.albums)
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what the error says ?  paste the error please

Comment: @Ali I wasn't able to add the image directly. Attached a link.

Comment: @KarthigeyanKalyan is there a reason why the axios and firebase requests are outside of a life cycle method such as componentDidMount?

Comment: No specific reason, @JoshuaLeonard. Just wanted to keep all the imports together; anyway thought it wouldn't hurt to have the imports throughout the runtime of the app

Comment: i get this same problem with https://github.com/HandlebarLabs/currency-converter-starter/blob/module-3-lesson-4-logo/app/components/Logo/Logo.js

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add a `<Text>` tag around Text inside of `<Button>`, or you can throw the text in the title attribute.

```
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
            <Text>Log Out</Text>
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
```

Comment: I pass the 'Log Out' text as a child to the prop and it is embedded into a <Text> tag in the <Button> component. So I don't think the problem is that; I just tried it out anyway, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from GitHub (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243#issuecomment-335488473):

> I got this error in RN 0.49.1 in some conditional JSX that relied on a
>   value's being truthy to decide whether a View shows up or not. I fixed
>   the error using the classic double exclamation !!, i.e. "{!!value"
>   instead of "{value."

It helps me

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `console.log(...)` in this method

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText='Authentication' />
        console.log(this.state.albums) ==> HERE 
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );   
}
```

you can do :

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.albums);
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText='Authentication' />

        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );   
}
```

---

also the `Button` cannot accept text you should wrap it in `<Text>` Component like this

```
<Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
    <Text>Log Out</Text>
</Button>
```

Comment: Just as I explained above, the text is being passed on as a child to the prop. So the mistake is somewhere else I suppose. Any other ideas? The change to console.log also didn't make a difference.