# ListItem is not rendering in FlatList of React Native

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I want to render 2 buttons in flatlist but on doing that shows the error I mentioned in O/p . But I rendered a Text component in place of Button then it rendered

```
const [formValue,setValue]=React.useState(
                                          [
                                            {
                                                p_id:0,
                                                projectName:'Project Name',
                                                task:'Task Details',
                                                date:'Date',
                                                startTime:'Start Time',
                                                endTime:'End Time',
                                                hrs:'Total Hrs',
                                                edit: <View>
                                                        <Button title="Edit Status" />
                                                        <Button title="Delete Status" />
                                                      </View>
                                                            
                                              }
                                           ]

                                          )

     <FlatList scrollEnabled={true} 
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      data={formValue}
      renderItem={({item,index}) => (
                              <ListItem>
                                <ListItem.Content   key={item.p_id}>
                                  
                                  <ListItem.Title>  
                                    {item.projectName}
                                  </ListItem.Title>

                                  <ListItem.Title>  
                                    {item.task}
                                  </ListItem.Title> 

                                  <ListItem.Title>  
                                    {item.startTime}
                                  </ListItem.Title>

                                  <ListItem.Title>  
                                    {item.startTime}
                                  </ListItem.Title>

                                  <ListItem.Title>  
                                    {item.endTime}
                                  </ListItem.Title>
                                 
                                  <ListItem.Title>  
                                    {item.edit}    {/* Problem is here as it is not rendering in 
                                                      React native*/}
                                  </ListItem.Title> 

                                </ListItem.Content>   
                              </ListItem> 
                          )
                       }    
       />
```

O/p: Can't add a yoga node without any major function

Please suggest me some solutions . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please add source of ListItem

Comment: try to look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48360297/7858922

Answer (score 0):

You may try using View within the render item

```
<FlatList
          data={formValue}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
                <Text>{ item.projectName }</Text>
                <Text>{ item.task }</Text>
                ....
                { item.edit } // render view
            </View>
          )}
          ....

/>
```